# Check user and redirect from login form (Symfony 5.4+)

Tags: symfony

I have a problem. I created verificator via Mailtrap.io and standart login form via Symfony console. And then I want to check user before login via email if his email has been verified. So, how can I redirect from LoginFromAuthenticator and add flash to notificated them?

```
class LoginFromAuthenticator extends AbstractLoginFormAuthenticator
{
    use TargetPathTrait;

    public const LOGIN_ROUTE = 'main_login';

    private UrlGeneratorInterface $urlGenerator;

    public function __construct(UrlGeneratorInterface $urlGenerator)
    {
        $this->urlGenerator = $urlGenerator;
    }

    public function authenticate(Request $request): Passport
    {
        $email = $request->request->get('email', '');

        $request->getSession()->set(Security::LAST_USERNAME, $email);

        return new Passport(
            new UserBadge($email),
            new PasswordCredentials($request->request->get('password', '')),
            [
                new CsrfTokenBadge('authenticate', $request->request->get('_csrf_token')),
                new RememberMeBadge()
            ]
        );
    }

    public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token, string $firewallName): ?Response
    {
        if ($targetPath = $this->getTargetPath($request->getSession(), $firewallName)) {
            return new RedirectResponse($targetPath);
        }

         return new RedirectResponse($this->urlGenerator->generate('main_homepage'));
    }

    protected function getLoginUrl(Request $request): string
    {
        return $this->urlGenerator->generate(self::LOGIN_ROUTE);
    }
}

class SecurityController extends AbstractController
{
    #[Route(path: '/login', name: 'main_login')]
    public function login(AuthenticationUtils $authenticationUtils): Response
    {
        // if ($this->getUser()) {
        //     return $this->redirectToRoute('target_path');
        // }

        // get the login error if there is one
        $error = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();
        // last username entered by the user
        $lastUsername = $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername();

        return $this->render('security/login.html.twig', ['last_username' => $lastUsername, 'error' => $error]);
    }

    #[Route(path: '/logout', name: 'main_logout')]
    public function logout(): void
    {
        throw new \LogicException('This method can be blank - it will be intercepted by the logout key on your firewall.');
    }
}
```

Comment: There is already a bundle for this, it will create the `isVerified` method and add it to your User entity, also will update your loginAuthenticator. Do `composer install symfonycasts/verify-email-bundle`

Comment: Essentially, you need a badge which you can mark as resolved when the email is verified and otherwise the login will fail and redirect with flash message. You will then need an event listener/subscriber registered to the CheckPassportEvent, get the user (via passport from the user badge) and check if the email is verified. Showing all the code is a bit much. Just let me know, which part you struggle with exactly and I might be able to create an answer with the specifics.